# Chrome Extension Manifest V3 Visual Problems

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The weirdest thing is happening;

With my extension enabled, certain web pages appear normally, but the non-visible parts have their background color changed to black. So, everything looks fine until you scroll. Here's an example with my extension enabled:
[image]

Here it is with my extension turned off:
[image]

Again, this only happens for some web pages (many are fine) and only for their non-visible (i.e., scrollable) parts.

The only DOM manipulation happening is in `popup.js`, which, anyway I believe doesn't fire unless you click the extension icon (right?). And by "DOM manipulation", I mean:

```
document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').innerHTML =  "Sign out";
document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').style.color = '#fff';
```

... nothing more. There's nothing in my `contentScript.js` nor `background.js` (which, anyway, is the background service worker).

In terms of `manifest.json` permissions, this is what I have:

```
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "identity"
  ]
```

-- EDIT --
As requested, here's the complete `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "XXX",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon_16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon_32.png",
    "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "XXX",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "identity"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "css": ["contentScript.css"]
    }
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes":["openid", "email", "profile"]
  },
  "key": "XXX"
}
```

Here's the complete `popup.js`:

```
'use strict';
import './popup.css';
import '@lottiefiles/lottie-player';

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Events

// Fire every time extension icon is clicked
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateButtonText);

document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').style.color = '#1fa3ec';
  document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').classList.add("button--loading");
  
  getStarted();
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Event logic

const subscriptionHTML = '<a href="https://www.example.com/#plans" target="_blank"  style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(29, 78, 109);">Subscribe for $1.</a>';

function updateButtonText() {
  // Send msg to background
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'isUserSignedIn' }, (response) => {
    if (response.response === 'YES') {
      document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').innerHTML = "Sign out";
      document.getElementById('signedInAsLbl').innerHTML = `Signed in as ${response.email}`;
      document.getElementById('getASubscriptionLbl').innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').innerHTML = "Sign in";
      document.getElementById('signedInAsLbl').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('getASubscriptionLbl').innerHTML = subscriptionHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').style.color = '#fff';
    document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').classList.remove("button--loading");
  });
}

function getStarted() {
 // Send msg to background
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'getStarted', payload: { message: "Let's get started!"}}, (response) => {
    if (response.response === 'YES') {
      document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').innerHTML = "Sign out";
      document.getElementById('signedInAsLbl').innerHTML = `Signed in as ${response.email}`;
      document.getElementById('getASubscriptionLbl').innerHTML = "";
    } else if (response === 'NO') {
      document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').innerHTML = "Sign in";
      document.getElementById('signedInAsLbl').innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById('getASubscriptionLbl').innerHTML = subscriptionHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').style.color = '#fff';
    document.getElementById('getStartedBtn').classList.remove("button--loading");
  });
}
```

And here's `button--loading` CSS class from `popup.css`, responsible for a loading spinning circle on the sign in/out button:

```
.button--loading::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: button-loading-spinner 1s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
  from {
      transform: rotate(0turn);
  }

  to {
      transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I can't see why this is happening.

Comment: The code you've posted is unrelated. The problem is either caused by a different part of your code or it's a bug in Chrome in which case you can use the [bisect-builds](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/) script to find when it happened.

Comment: Was just trying to share context. Thanks for the script, will take a look.

Comment: @ppp - Can you post your complete manifest.json and popup.js?